# MKPolyLineRenderer change color without removing overlay

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am developing an application that almost replicates Apple maps application behavior. When i touch a route, i need to change its color to blue and change the other ones colors to gray. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this without having to remove the overlays and adding them again ? Thanks.

Comment: This answer solves it perfectly. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30193650/3324388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

1. Make sure your annotation view has `enabled = YES`.
2. Implement `-[MKMapViewDelegate mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:]`.
3. In that callback, get `view` and change its properties.

Comment: This is for the annotation not the MKPolylineRenderer.