# MKPolyline / MKPolyline renderer change color animation

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolyline

I working on app that relate with map and polyline.
I want to animate color changing of polyline what I have to do to achieve this.

I search to properly method all days yesterday and decide to ask question today.

Something like this code do but do on MKPolyline:

```
//Assume that this view is a line shape.
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 5);
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}];
```

So far I have:

Subclass of MKPolylineRenderer

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    CGFloat baseWidth = self.lineWidth / zoomScale;
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
    CGContextAddPath(context, self.path);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, baseWidth * 4);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, self.lineCap);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
}
```

In viewController.m

Adding polyline

```
- (void)addPolylineToMap {
    CustomPolyline *polyline = [CustomPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:[coordinateArray count]];
    polyline.lineID = polylineID;
    [mapView addOverlay:polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
}
```

Changing polyline color (Thanks to Anna #Ref:[MKPolyline / MKPolylineRenderer changing color without remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186902/mkpolyline-mkpolylinerenderer-changing-color-without-remove-it/30193650#30193650))

```
- (void)changingPolylineColor {
    for (MKPolyline *overlays in [mapView overlays]) {
        if ([overlays isKindOfClass:[CustomPolyline class]]) {
            CustomPolylineRenderer *renderer = (CustomPolylineRenderer *)[mapView rendererForOverlay:overlays];
            renderer.strokeColor = [self getColorFromArrayWithLineID:[(CustomPolyline *)overlays lineID]];
            [renderer invalidatePath];
        }
    }
}
```

MapViewDelegate renderForOverlay:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[CustomPolyline class]]) {
        polylineView = [[CustomPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        polylineView.strokeColor = [self getColorFromArrayWithLineID:[(CustomPolyline *)overlay lineID]];
        polylineView.alpha = 0.5f;
        polylineView.lineWidth = 4.0f;
        return polylineView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

So what I need is when I call `[self changingPolylineColor];` the polyline on map has change color with animation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any updates on this?